# Spring security - 403 error after logging out and goin to /admin path

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a problem with Spring Security in my project. I made a simple login/register app from one course on internet. I wanted to add logout, but it's not working - it's giving me 403 error (Acces Denied). After clicking "Log out" on home.jsp it's giving me Acces Denied page. I made privileges in my security-context file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="John" authorities="admin"
                password="letmein" />
            <security:user name="Zog" authorities="admin"
                password="iamzog" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>

    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" />
    </security:authentication-provider>

</security:authentication-manager>

<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('admin')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/createaccount" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/docreate" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/offercreated" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/loggedout" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/newaccount" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/createnewaccount" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/accountcreated" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/accounts" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />
    <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/loggedout" />
</security:http>
```

My HomeController.java for /admin:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showHome(Model model) {
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/admin")
    public String showAdmin(Model model) {
        return "admin";
    }
}
```

My LoginController.java with loggedout:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    private UsersService usersService;

    @Autowired
    public void setUsersService(UsersService usersService) {
        this.usersService = usersService;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String showLogin() {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/loggedout")
    public String showLoggedOut() {
        return "loggedout";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/newaccount")
    public String showNewAccount(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "newaccount";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/createnewaccount", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createAccount(@Valid User user, BindingResult result){

        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "newaccount";    
        }

        user.setAuthority("user");
        user.setEnabled(true);

        if(usersService.exists(user.getUsername())) {
            System.out.println("Caught duplicate username.");
            result.rejectValue("username", "DuplicateKey.user.username");
            return "newaccount";
        }

        try {
            usersService.create(user);
        } catch (DuplicateKeyException e) {
            result.rejectValue("username", "DuplicateKey.user.username");
            return "newaccount";
        }

        return "accountcreated";
    }

}
```

And home.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<p><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/accounts">Show current accounts.</a></p>
<p><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/createaccount">Add a new offert.</a></p>
<p><a href="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_logout' />">Log out.</a></p>



</body>
</html>
```

Similar error I have when I want to go to /admin path - I'm getting Acces Denied too. In database I have accounts with 'user' authorities/roles and one with 'admin'. I use this 'admin' roled account to go to /admin, but it still don't work. 
Do you need something else (files/sources) from my project?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: hasAuthority('admin') worked for administrator! :) So there is only one problem left - logging out.

Comment: Ok, i made it with something called csrf.